# Cannot install INTL extension with XAMPP on Mac

Tags: php, macos, xampp, moodle, intl

When I wrote `sudo pecl install intl` command on terminal I get the following error.

My path is `Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php`.

I wrote `extension=intl.so` in `php.ini` file in etc.

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl.so' (tried: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/intl.so (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/intl.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_string_init_interned
  Referenced from: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/intl.so
 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/intl.so), /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/intl.so.so (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/intl.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Can someone help ?